# Unable to install Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2005

After downloading *Visual Studio 2005 SP1* and *Visual Studio 2005 Upgrade for Vista* to install *Visual Studio 2005* on Windows 7, when I tried to intall *Visual Studio 2005 SP1*, I got this error message:

> The up patch cannot be installed by the windows installer service because the program to be upgraded is missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of program. Verify that the program to be updated exist on your computer and you have correct upgrade patch

I have saved `VS80sp1-KB926601-X86-ENU (1)` and `VS80sp1-KB932232-X86-ENU` on the `D:` drive.

What should I do to install Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7?

Comment: Did you install the base version of VS2005 first before trying to install the service packs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Where is Visual Studio 2005 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780741/where-is-visual-studio-2005-express)

[Visual Studio on Windows Vista and Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa948853)

Search is our friend...

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment and after re-reading your question again.

You need to to install the original version of Visual Studio 2005 **before** installing the service packs.

The service packs **don't** contain the original program, just all the patches and hotfixes rolled into one installer.

Comment: thnx for answer but i am nt able to find correct link from where i can download original version visual studio 2005..can u send a verified link of dat which will be compatible with windows 7.....

Comment: @div - I'm not sure that VS2005 is still available. If you've searched but not found I don't think I'll be any more successful.

Comment: while installing vs2005 professional ...i am getting dis error"the windows installer package"d:\softwares\microsoft visual studio 8\vs_setup.msi could not be opened.chooose retry to try again.choose cancel for exit setup"....i am not able to proceed further after retry....what shud i do?